# how to notify that a netdev queue could receive packets again

Tags: c, linux, networking, kernel

I want to put packets in a netdev queue

```
err = dev_queue_xmit(skb);
if (err) 
    {
    ... stop processing ... sleep ...
    }
```

is there any way to register a notifier which tells me that the queue could now receive packets again? If not I have to poll, but I dislike :-)

Comment: I don't see a way. When the queue frees up, net_tx_action is called, but I don't see that you set you callback there.

Comment: Is there no standard way to handle a full tx queue on a netdevice? If not I have to create a tasklet, timer or something else, which try to write again after a while? Looks not very satisfying.

Answer (score 0):

The queue maintained for the packet backlogs is at /proc/sys/net/core/netdev_max_backlog.
To get the kernel values(here packets received) from /proc/sys/ you can use sysctl system call. Please be careful in using that (should not modify the value). If the threshold is achieved you can trigger a message using software interrupt through your notifier.